# Add Expires headers to Azure Hosted wordpress

Tags: windows, wordpress, apache, azure, iis

Using Azure Hosted WordPress, I was doing some performance testing for my website via http://gtmetrix.com.  My reports were suggesting to ***‘leverage browser caching’*** and ***‘add expires headers’*** to improve my performance grading.

So Even after updating `.htaccess` it wasn't getting updated, I noticed that it wasn’t making any difference to my performance reports – which got me thinking about **Azure and that it would be running IIS** in the backend and not `Apache` – and of course IIS doesn’t use the `.htaccess` file, it uses `web.config` instead.

So how do I Add Expires headers ??

Comment: I edited to try extracting some ore out of your post. But it looks like you didn't post on the right Exchange place. Have a try at http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/ if nothing goods comes here. Also you might do a little research to **know** what Azure uses.

Comment: Yeah as you said I have posted in the posted URL . Need to resolve the issue asap . Thank You though for replying .